# Splash screen alpha animation not working

Tags: java, android, android-animation

So I have an app that currently has two Activities. A SplashScreenActivity and a MainActivity. The transition between the two activities works just fine but the problem lies in the SplashScreenActivity itself. In it, there is a single ImageView that is supposed to be initially invisible and then fade in. But instead the image remains invisible the entire time. Please help. Here's the code:

The SplashScreenActivity:

```
package com.degioncloud;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

        ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_logo);

        logo.setImageAlpha(0);
        logo.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The XML of the SplashScreenActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreenActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.degioncloud">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DegionCloud">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The MainActivty is empty so I don't see a need to share that but if you need any other file then let me know and I will send a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `start()` for the animation to begin:

```
logo.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried adding the start method but unfortunately, the ImageView is still invisible for some reason

Comment: Can you remove setImageAlpha(0) and see if the image is shown at all?

Comment: When I remove it the screen is blank for a brief moment (I assume that's the default screen while the app is loading). The logo then appears for the duration I specified in the setDuration() and then fades out into the MainActivity. Honestly, it doesn't look too bad. I might just keep it like this.